# Asus Transformer Tab tf300t stuck on asus screen. No ADB, no fastboot, no recovery, no os

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, unbricking, fastboot, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I'm very happy with cm11 on my Galaxy s3 so i wanted to try it on my tf300t. 
First i unlocked the bootloader which i succeeded in doing.
Then i flashed clockworkmod recovery via adb. 
However, when i tried to enter the recovery, it didn't work. So i tried a couple of more times by turning the tablet off and re-trying to enter recovery.

That's when it all got terrible. While is was in fastboot mode (i had the three options of RCK, android and wipe) and i was trying to select "Android" with volume down but i pressed on too many and got "Wipe data" selected. Couldn't go back. And since then my device is stuck on the ASUS logo. Now it looks just like this:
[http://srv1.jpg.co.il/7/52e6c1d38d07a.jpg http://srv1.jpg.co.il/7/52e6c1d38d07a.jpg](http://srv1.jpg.co.il/7/52e6c1d38d07a.jpg)

And everytime i try to restart it just goes to this screen. I even tried manually resetting it with a paperclip. So now i'm kinda hopeless.

Please Help me!